# cc1: warnings being treated as errors when compile FreeBSD 8.2 Release

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, freebsd, make

I am trying to compile FreeBsd 8.2 RELEASE kernel

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE #2: Sun May 18 00:07:10 PDT 2014
```

Build the kernel

```
# pwd
/usr/src
# make buildkernel
```

... it compiles until I get this error ...

```
MAKE=make sh /usr/src/sys/conf/newvers.sh GENERIC
cc -c -O -pipe  -std=c99 -g -Wall -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Winline -Wcast-qual  -Wundef -Wno-pointer-sign -fformat-extensions -nostdinc  -I. -I/usr/src/sys -I/usr/src/sys/contrib/altq -D_KERNEL -DHAVE_KERNEL_OPTION_HEADERS -include opt_global.h -fno-common -finline-limit=8000 --param inline-unit-growth=100 --param large-function-growth=1000  -mno-align-long-strings -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2  -mno-mmx -mno-3dnow -mno-sse -mno-sse2 -mno-sse3 -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -Werror  vers.c
linking kernel.debug
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
9336435  915392  672984 10924811     a6b30b kernel.debug
objcopy --only-keep-debug kernel.debug kernel.symbols
objcopy --strip-debug --add-gnu-debuglink=kernel.symbols kernel.debug kernel
cd /usr/src/sys/modules; MAKEOBJDIRPREFIX=/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC/modules KMODDIR=/boot/kernel MODULES_OVERRIDE="usb/run" DEBUG_FLAGS="-g" MACHINE=i386 KERNBUILDDIR="/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC" SYSDIR="/usr/src/sys" make  all
===> usb/run (all)
cc -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -Werror -D_KERNEL -DKLD_MODULE -nostdinc   -DHAVE_KERNEL_OPTION_HEADERS -include /usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC/opt_global.h -I. -I@ -I@/contrib/altq -finline-limit=8000 --param inline-unit-growth=100 --param large-function-growth=1000 -fno-common -g -I/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC -mno-align-long-strings -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2  -mno-mmx -mno-3dnow -mno-sse -mno-sse2 -mno-sse3 -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -std=iso9899:1999 -fstack-protector -Wall -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Winline -Wcast-qual  -Wundef -Wno-pointer-sign -fformat-extensions -c /usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:150: error: 'USB_PRODUCT_CISCOLINKSYS_AE1000' undeclared here (not in a function)
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c: In function 'run_vap_delete':
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:861: error: 'struct run_vap' has no member named 'beacon_mbuf'
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:861: warning: passing argument 1 of 'm_freem' from incompatible pointer type
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:862: error: 'struct run_vap' has no member named 'beacon_mbuf'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:862: warning: statement with no effect
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c: In function 'run_newstate':
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:1809: error: 'struct run_vap' has no member named 'beacon_mbuf'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:1809: warning: passing argument 1 of 'm_freem' from incompatible pointer type
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:1810: error: 'struct run_vap' has no member named 'beacon_mbuf'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:1810: warning: statement with no effect
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c: In function 'run_key_set':
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2106: error: 'struct run_softc' has no member named 'cmdq_key_del'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2106: warning: passing argument 1 of 'atomic_load_acq_int' from incompatible pointer type
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c: In function 'run_key_delete_cb':
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2166: error: 'struct run_softc' has no member named 'cmdq_key_del'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2166: warning: passing argument 1 of 'atomic_clear_barr_int' from incompatible pointer type
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c: In function 'run_key_delete':
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2181: error: 'struct run_softc' has no member named 'cmdq_key_del'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2181: warning: passing argument 1 of 'atomic_set_barr_int' from incompatible pointer type
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c: In function 'run_drain_fifo':
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2284: error: 'struct run_softc' has no member named 'wcid_stats'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2284: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2285: error: 'RUN_TXCNT' undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2285: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2285: error: for each function it appears in.)
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2285: error: array subscript is not an integer
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2285: error: lvalue required as increment operand
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2285: warning: statement with no effect
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2287: error: 'RUN_SUCCESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2287: error: array subscript is not an integer
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2287: error: lvalue required as increment operand
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2287: warning: statement with no effect
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2298: error: array subscript is not an integer
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2298: warning: statement with no effect
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2299: error: 'RUN_RETRY' undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2299: error: array subscript is not an integer
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2299: warning: statement with no effect
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c: In function 'run_iter_func':
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2315: error: array type has incomplete element type
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2324: warning: cast discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2325: warning: passing argument 4 of 'run_read_region_1' makes integer from pointer without a cast
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2330: error: 'struct usb_device_id' has no member named 'error'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2330: error: request for member 'fail' in something not a structure or union
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2330: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2332: error: 'struct usb_device_id' has no member named 'tx'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2332: error: request for member 'retry' in something not a structure or union
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2332: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2333: error: 'struct usb_device_id' has no member named 'tx'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2333: error: request for member 'success' in something not a structure or union
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2333: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2334: error: 'struct usb_device_id' has no member named 'error'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2334: error: request for member 'fail' in something not a structure or union
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2334: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2336: error: 'struct usb_device_id' has no member named 'error'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2336: error: request for member 'fail' in something not a structure or union
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2336: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2339: error: 'struct run_softc' has no member named 'wcid_stats'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2339: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2341: error: 'struct run_softc' has no member named 'wcid_stats'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2341: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2342: error: 'struct run_softc' has no member named 'wcid_stats'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2342: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2345: error: 'RUN_TXCNT' undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2345: error: array subscript is not an integer
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2345: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2346: error: 'RUN_SUCCESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2346: error: array subscript is not an integer
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2346: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2347: error: 'RUN_RETRY' undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2347: error: array subscript is not an integer
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2347: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2315: warning: unused variable 'sta'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c: In function 'run_newassoc_cb':
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2378: error: 'struct run_softc' has no member named 'wcid_stats'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2378: error: 'struct run_softc' has no member named 'wcid_stats'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:2378: warning: passing argument 1 of 'memset' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c: In function 'run_update_beacon':
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:3990: error: 'struct run_vap' has no member named 'beacon_mbuf'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:3990: warning: passing argument 3 of 'ieee80211_beacon_update' from incompatible pointer type
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c: In function 'run_update_beacon_cb':
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:4019: error: 'struct run_vap' has no member named 'beacon_mbuf'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:4020: error: 'struct run_vap' has no member named 'beacon_mbuf'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:4021: warning: statement with no effect
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:4022: error: 'struct run_vap' has no member named 'beacon_mbuf'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:4025: error: 'struct run_vap' has no member named 'beacon_mbuf'
/usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run/../../../dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c:4025: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src/sys/modules/usb/run.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src/sys/modules.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src.
```

I am not sure how to assess this error message and fix it.

Any recommended directions?

### UPDATE TRIED ON ANOTHER VM

Got a similar error message

```
cc -static -o rescue rescue.o cat.lo chflags.lo chio.lo chmod.lo cp.lo date.lo dd.lo df.lo echo.lo ed.lo expr.lo getfacl.lo hostname.lo kenv.lo kill.lo ln.lo ls.lo mkdir.lo mv.lo pkill.lo ps.lo pwd.lo realpath.lo rm.lo rmdir.lo setfacl.lo sh.lo stty.lo sync.lo test.lo rcp.lo csh.lo atacontrol.lo badsect.lo camcontrol.lo ccdconfig.lo clri.lo devfs.lo dmesg.lo dump.lo dumpfs.lo dumpon.lo fsck.lo fsck_ffs.lo fsck_msdosfs.lo fsdb.lo fsirand.lo gbde.lo geom.lo ifconfig.lo init.lo kldconfig.lo kldload.lo kldstat.lo kldunload.lo ldconfig.lo md5.lo mdconfig.lo mdmfs.lo mknod.lo mount.lo mount_cd9660.lo mount_msdosfs.lo mount_nfs.lo mount_ntfs.lo mount_nullfs.lo mount_udf.lo mount_unionfs.lo newfs.lo newfs_msdos.lo nos-tun.lo ping.lo reboot.lo restore.lo rcorder.lo route.lo routed.lo rtquery.lo rtsol.lo savecore.lo spppcontrol.lo swapon.lo sysctl.lo tunefs.lo umount.lo atmconfig.lo ping6.lo ipf.lo zfs.lo zpool.lo bsdlabel.lo sconfig.lo fdisk.lo dhclient.lo head.lo mt.lo sed.lo tail.lo tee.lo gzip.lo bzip2.lo xz.lo tar.lo vi.lo id.lo chroot.lo chown.lo /usr/src/rescue/rescue/../librescue/exec.o /usr/src/rescue/rescue/../librescue/getusershell.o /usr/src/rescue/rescue/../librescue/login_class.o /usr/src/rescue/rescue/../librescue/popen.o /usr/src/rescue/rescue/../librescue/rcmdsh.o /usr/src/rescue/rescue/../librescue/sysctl.o /usr/src/rescue/rescue/../librescue/system.o -lcrypt -ledit -lkvm -ll -ltermcap -lutil -lalias -lcam -lcurses -ldevstat -lipsec -lipx -lzfs -lnvpair -luutil -lavl -lgeom -lbsdxml -ljail -lkiconv -lmd -lreadline -lsbuf -lufs -lz -lbz2 -llzma -larchive -lcrypto -lm
csh.lo(.text+0xdba6): In function `nlsclose':
: undefined reference to `dl_iconv_close'
csh.lo(.text+0xdd21): In function `nlsinit':
: undefined reference to `dl_iconv_open'
csh.lo(.text+0xde1c): In function `iconv_catgets':
: undefined reference to `dl_iconv'
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src/rescue/rescue.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src/rescue/rescue.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src/rescue.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases those are not primarily warnings that break the build.

For the kernel compilation:

```
error: 'struct run_vap' has no member named 'beacon_mbuf'
```

the compiler tells you, that the code is trying to access something that isn't there. This may have many reasons, but generally it suggests that the code is broken. Maybe you are trying to compile a module that relies on newer/older internal kernel API (i.e. is using another definition of structures than the rest of the kernel).

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'm_freem' from incompatible pointer type
```

is often either a programming mistake (i.e. indeed passing something else as argument than what is expected) or a missing cast operator.

```
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
```

is caused by `-Werror` in the compiler flags, which tells the compiler to treat warnings as errors. Which is usually a Good Idea<sup>TM</sup>, actually (mostly because of the often encountered - *"But it compiles, there are just some warnings"* attitude).

For the other problem:

```
csh.lo(.text+0xdba6): In function `nlsclose':
: undefined reference to `dl_iconv_close'
```

is actually an error from the linker - compilation went (more or less) well but you are not supplying external libraries that provide some symbols referenced by the code. This often happens when you correctly `#include` header files and then forget to tell linker to actually link against that library (usually the `-l` option).

Comment: these notes were a lot of help to get me started. I am not sure I need a lot more to close the issue. thanks